# Cancel TimerTask on application crash

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android application in which I have to execute some tasks at very short intervals 20-30seconds. It is a requirement, it is somehow a "monitoring" app and it won't be for commercial purposes so no need to worry about battery and data usage.

I am scheduling tasks using `java.util.Timer` like this :

```
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mUpdateDataTask,0,20000);
```

I know how to stop the tasks being executed using :

```
mTimer.cancel();
```

and I am doing this when my `Service` is stopped.

**THE PROBLEM**:
If my app crashes at some point, the `onDestroy()` method of the `Service` is not called and the `mTimer` never gets canceled, and those task keep getting executed. How can I be sure that they are canceled when my app crashes or it is force stopped from the Settings->Application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) as a way of catching the crash; you can cancel the timers in this handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest wrapping your code with try-catch blocks and if app crashes, do all clean-up in finally block.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have your Task contain a weak reference to the `Service` and, each time it gets executed, check if the `Service` is still valid. Not the prettiest solution but may work ;)